# Comparison between plate and cylindrical capacitor

Tags: electrostatics

I needed to find the electric field between two cylindrical surfaces, which together build a cylindrical capacitor and both have height h. So I immediately used the Gauss theorem to do so. But the problem is that the result that I get, the way I get it is not similar to how I find the electric field for a plate capacitor.

For a plate capacitor we have:

For a single infinite hom. charged plate the electric field is : $E=\frac {\eta}{2\epsilon_0}$

For a plate capacitor : The field in between is a sum of the ele. field generated by the negative and positive charged plates, which means $E=\frac {\eta}{\epsilon_0}$. So the double of a single plate.

Now with the same logic I tried to find the electric field between the two charged cylinders, where the positive cylinder is the one with the smaller radius. As a result, by considering only the positive (+Q) charged cylinder I get:

$E=\frac Q {2 \pi h \rho \epsilon_0}$

And like above I would multiply it by 2, two find the field between the two cylinders. But apparently that is not correct.Each plate contributes to the total field correct?

Why this difference in finding the field between these 2 different capacitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not applying G's theorem correctly in the case of the cylindrical capacitor. Take away the inner cylinder, leaving just the outer charged cylinder. Now consider a co-axial, cylindrical Gaussian surface inside the outer cylinder. According to G's theorem no net electric flux will pass through the Gaussian cylinder. So, by symmetry, the electric field strength will be zero all over the Gaussian cylinder. We conclude that the outer charged cylinder does not contribute to the field between the cylinders of a charged cylindrical capacitor.

Now use an appropriate (symmetry preserving) Gaussian surface to show why both *flat* plates of a parallel plate capacitor (plate dimension >> plate separation) *do* contribute to the field between the plates.

Comment: But that is what I did in the case of the cylindrical capacitor, I took into consideration a coaxial surface between the two cylinders. Initially I took into consideration only the positive (with smaller radius) cylinder and I got the above mentioned formula. Is it because the surface I am considering doesn't enclose the negative charged plate that I shouldn't consider it's contribution ?

Comment: And does that mean that in the case of the plate capacitor I take a gausian cylinder which includes some circular surface in both plates?

Comment: (a) "Is it because the surface I am considering doesn't enclose the negative charged plate that I shouldn't consider it's contribution ?" YES ! (b) "And does that mean that in the case of the plate capacitor I take a gausian cylinder which includes some circular surface in both plates?" You should try for yourself various Gaussian surfaces, but keep their end-faces parallel to the plates, so as to keep the flat plate symmetry.

Comment: Thanks for the help